# find sum of n terms of series $\sum \cos(n\theta)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Use the result $1 + z + z^2...+z^n=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$ to sum the series to n terms

$1+\cos\theta+\cos2\theta+...$

also show that partial sums of series $\sum \cos (n\theta)$ is bounded when $0<\theta<\pi/2$

My attempt

so z  can be written as $e^{i\theta}$ which means:

$1+ \cos \theta + \cos 2\theta ....+\cos n\theta + i(\sin \theta+\sin 2\theta+....+\sin n\theta)=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$

after this.. i dont know

Comment: Do you know of a certain famous formula involving $cos$ and $sin$ and something else?

Comment: What if $z$ was a complex number written in polar coordinates?

Comment: This can be done using DE MOIVRE'S theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that 
$$
e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t\;\;\;\;\forall t\in\Bbb C
$$
and that
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n}z^j=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}\;\;\forall z\in\Bbb C,\;\;|z|<1.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\cos(j\theta)=
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\Re{(e^{ij\theta})}=
\Re\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}(e^{ij\theta})\right)=
\Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i\theta(n+1)}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right)
$$
The last term I wrote can be handled easily in order to be written explicitly and get the results you wanted.

Comment: since we know the sum of series $\sum cos n\theta$ does this imply it is bounded irrespective of $\theta$?

Comment: For this purpose, write explicitly the last term I've written. Split $(1-e^{i\theta(n+1)})/(1-e^{i\theta})$ into its real and imaginary part.